# Get URL from HTML file using FindStr

Tags: windows, command-line, findstr

I'd like to preface this by saying that I'm very new to the command prompt and I've been only using it for some WGET and YOUTUBE-DL, and that I'm on a Windows 8 PC.

I'd like to get a bunch of links from an html file. The links all start with

`https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/`

and end with

`.jpg`

Right now I'm using this:

`findstr ^https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/originals/.*\.jpg index.html > urls.txt`

I did some research and I'm using the "range" function of FINDSTR as you can see. But I still get a lot of extra text that I'm not interested in. Is there anyway to trim it down?

Comment: [now you have two problems](http://nedbatchelder.com/blog/201204/two_problems.html). HTML is too complex for findstr or regex in general. Any findstr solution will eventually break

Answer (score 3):

As [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454) states, you really shouldn't atempt to parse [X]HTML with regex. *findstr* has very limited regex support in any case.

Use a proper HTML scraper/parser like [Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html) instead. A command like the following will do what you're looking for:

```
xidel <URL or HTML file name> -q -e "//a/extract(@href/resolve-uri(.), 'https:\/\/s-media-cache-ak0\.pinimg\.com\/originals\/.*?\.jpg')[. != '']"
```